# Can I do a wipe transition using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I have the following snippet of example code (I am using React but do not feel like spending time sanitising the actual project code before posting that here):

```js
let menuOpened = false;

document.getElementById('menu-button')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      menuOpened = !menuOpened;
      document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
      document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

body.menu-opened {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body > * {
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  background-color: #6FC5C2;
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #80CAF1;
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  transition: all 0.35s ease;
  visibility: hidden;
  z-index: 20;
  
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav.menu-opened {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: #9C9ECF;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #F8CFD7;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  padding: 2rem;
  
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  border: ridge #80CAF1;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  min-height: 15vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  align-items: center;
}

article:last-child {
  border-width: 3px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #016CBA;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <header>
    <button id="menu-button" type="button">Menu</button>
  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="/">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/">Link 2</a>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
    <aside>Filter Form</aside>
    <section>
      <article>Article A</article>
      <article>Article B</article>
      <article>Article C</article>
      <article>Article D</article>
      <article>Article E</article>
      <article>Article F</article>
      <article>Article G</article>
      <article>Article H</article>
      <article>Article I</article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Currently, when I click the button to open the navigation menu, the page will disable scrolling and the menu will fade in. When I click the button again, scrolling will be re-enabled and the menu will fade out.

What I actually want is a wipe transition instead of fading, like so:

[image]

Using the above image as an analogy, the main page content would be A, and the menu would be B. However, instead of horizontal I want the wipe to be vertical i.e. when I open the menu, the wipe will go from top to bottom, and when I close the menu, the wipe will go from bottom to top. The menu text should not be moving. I want to use the same transition duration and timing function as currently configured.

Is this possible without using JavaScript/React?

Comment: Add to menu: `translateY` `-100%`, `height: 100vh` and use a transition (`100ms` is good). This puts the menu above the screen. 

Add to `menu-opened` : `translateY` to `0`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: @mikemaccana That gives me a slide transition, not wipe. When it transits in and out, the text is moving in and out too. What I want is for the menu to already be in its final position, but transiting to cover the main content from top to bottom. Kind of like rolling a wallpaper downwards, I guess?

Comment: you're right, my mistake. If you make a codesandbox with this I'll do a wipe for you. Or if you want to solve it yourself, you're going to go from `width: 0` to `width : 100vw` with a transition.

Answer (score 2):

Another idea using `clip-path`

```js
let menuOpened = false;

document.getElementById('menu-button')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      menuOpened = !menuOpened;
      document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
      document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

body.menu-opened {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body > * {
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  background-color: #6FC5C2;
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #80CAF1;
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  transition: all 0.8s ease;
  z-index: 20;
  
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,0% 0,-200px 100%,0 100%);
}

nav.menu-opened {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0,calc(100% + 200px) 0,100% 100%,0 100%);
}

a {
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: #9C9ECF;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #F8CFD7;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  padding: 2rem;
  
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  border: ridge #80CAF1;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  min-height: 15vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  align-items: center;
}

article:last-child {
  border-width: 3px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #016CBA;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <header>
    <button id="menu-button" type="button">Menu</button>
  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a href="/">Link 1</a>
    <a href="/">Link 2</a>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
    <aside>Filter Form</aside>
    <section>
      <article>Article A</article>
      <article>Article B</article>
      <article>Article C</article>
      <article>Article D</article>
      <article>Article E</article>
      <article>Article F</article>
      <article>Article G</article>
      <article>Article H</article>
      <article>Article I</article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

now, you use it with `visibility` yes?
don't use it!

use `height: 0;`
then when you want open it in js convert it to `height: 100%` or another size.

and use `transition: height .5s;` for open as an animation.

Comment: The effect I get is that the menu is growing/stretching downwards when it opens. Reference the gif image again, the text shouldn't be moving, the menu should instead be "rolling" downwards to cover up the content underneath

Comment: use your text in a span tag, and use ```position: absolute;``` css style.

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around, I've finally found a solution that gives me the desired effect:

```js
let menuOpened = false;

document.getElementById('menu-button')
    .addEventListener('click', function() {
      menuOpened = !menuOpened;
      document.getElementById('body').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
      document.getElementById('menu').classList.toggle('menu-opened', menuOpened);
    });
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body.menu-opened {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

body > * {
  width: 100vw;
}

header {
  background-color: #6FC5C2;
  display: flex;
  height: 20vh;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav {
  background-color: #80CAF1;
  clip-path: inset(0 0 80vh);
  display: flex;
  height: 80vh;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  position: fixed;
  top: 20vh;
  transition: clip-path 0.35s ease;
  z-index: 20;
  
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

nav.menu-opened {
  clip-path: inset(0);
}

a {
  color: black;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

main {
  display: flex;
}

aside {
  background-color: #9C9ECF;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 3rem 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  
  justify-content: center;
}

section {
  background-color: #F8CFD7;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 75%;
  padding: 2rem;
  
  align-items: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
}

article {
  border: ridge #80CAF1;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  min-height: 15vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  
  align-items: center;
}

article:last-child {
  border-width: 3px;
}

footer {
  background-color: #016CBA;
  height: 30vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
  <header>
    <button id="menu-button" type="button">Menu</button>
  </header>
  <nav id="menu">
    <a>Link 1</a>
    <a>Link 2</a>
  </nav>
  <main id="main">
    <aside>Filter Form</aside>
    <section>
      <article>Article A</article>
      <article>Article B</article>
      <article>Article C</article>
      <article>Article D</article>
      <article>Article E</article>
      <article>Article F</article>
      <article>Article G</article>
      <article>Article H</article>
      <article>Article I</article>
    </section>
  </main>
  <footer id="footer"></footer>
</body>
```

The trick is to use `clip-path` to create a mask over the menu.