# CSS - How to create a color transition from the corner?

Tags: css, css-transitions

What is the best way to create a CSS color transition to fill a div from the top right corner?

[image]

```css
#box {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}
```

```html
<div id='box'></div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66641065/704803 Think you will have to do something like this using clip-path if you want a “wipe” transition to occur

Answer (score 0):

You can use `linear-gradient` and the direction on your `background-image`:

```css
#box{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, blue, white);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</body>
```

or you also can use angles:

```css
#box{
    border: 2px solid blue;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    transition: 0.5s ease;
    background-image: linear-gradient(225deg, blue, white);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box">
    </div>
</body>
```